# Unable to align Card to bottom of Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I was following the tutorial from the Android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/cards.html) but they're not doing what I would expect them to.

I have created a CardFrame to display a Card on the watch and use the attribute `app:layout_box="bottom"` to have it appear on the bottom of the watch, but as you can see by the screenshot that was not the case. Here is my XML:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_scroll_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_box="bottom">

        <android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="Custom Title"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="Custom Description"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame>
    </android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

And here is a screenshot of the Card:

[image]

Can anyone shed some light onto why that attribute isn't working as expected?

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. The card appears on the top instead of the bottom. In case I find a solution, will update here. I suspect the interpretation of the attribute "layout_box" is probably incorrect.

Comment: Update: Found a solution to the problem, check my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an attribute **android:layout_gravity="bottom"** to the **CardFrame** tag, like so:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
```

This fixed the problem for me, and the card appears on the bottom.

Explanation:
I think the meaning of the attribute "layout_box" is not very clear from the cardframe tutorial. From the BoxInsetLayout [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/BoxInsetLayout.html), it appears that the layout_box="bottom" means "make sure that the bottom of the CardScrollView is contained (or boxed) inside the [centre box](http://developer.android.com/wear/images/02_uilib.png)". This prevents the bottom of the card from being cropped off. It does not mean "align at the bottom". The layout_gravity attribute places the card at the bottom. The layout_box attribute makes sure the bottom of the card content is not cropped off.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted for trying and testing this out, happy to accept once I verify it as well. Do you think I should submit a bug report for that docs page, if that's not complete code? The docs should do what they say they do.

Comment: Also, reading your paragraph did you test this on a round watch? You may need both attributes on a round watch. One to make sure it is on the bottom, and one to make sure it doesn't get cropped off. I will also verify later.

Comment: Yes, you can submit a bug report. The xml in the docs page does not match what they say it is supposed to output. I tested my code on the android round wear emulator. Yes, both attributes are necessary. If you do not specify the layout_box attribute on a round watch, the resulting card content sometimes goes out of the centre_box (depending on the size of the card content).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was writing a blog post about this and when I tested it for a screenshot it was driving me crazy, I couldn't bring myself to post incorrect information ha.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199671&thanks=199671&ts=1453860743